# Redirect 301 from /post.html to /post/ after permalink change in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I changed permalink from /post.html to /post/

I used this code in .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)\.html http://example.com/$1
```

The posts redirect work well, but if I go to homepage, I see http://example.com/index with 404 error

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `negative lookahead` to avoid matching `index`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!index).+?)\.html$ http://example.com/$1
```